# Loopback packet from FTTH modem for every 2 seconds

Tags: networking, router, ethernet, modem, loopback

To investigate some network problem, I had installed WireShark. I could see "broadcast LOOP unknown function" packets are constantly coming. The packet is like this.

> FF FF FF FF FF FF (6 bytes, broadcast)
>
> 00 25 a6 XX XX XX (6 bytes, "CentralN" MAC address. For privacy, I used XX).
>
> 90 00 (2 bytes, Configuration Test Protocol, loopback)
>
> 00 00 ... (60 bytes of 0's)

None of my devices had that MAC address, I never even had heard a manufacturer CentralN before. So to check it I turned off all my devices, and found that if I disconnect the FTTH modem from my router, I did not get those packets.

So, if my guess is correct, the FTTH modem is sending the packets to my router, and the router is broadcasting the packets to my network. The packets are sent for every 2 seconds. Is this normal or is my router malfunctioning?

[image]

Comment: According to www.coffer.com, `0025a6-xxxxxx` belongs to `Central Network Solution Co., Ltd.` (S.Korea). What is your modem manufacturer?

Comment: On the bottom, it says "Central Network Solution". So, I was right that those packets come from the FTTH modem. I found their web site from Google. I submitted this question there, but I am not sure I could get answers from them. Isn't the link between the modem and the router is a separate network from the link between the router and the computers?